# Electric potential between electron and proton is given as a function of $r$, how to find the variation of $r_n$ wrt $n$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential, atomic-physics

The electric potential between a proton and an electron is given by $V=V_0\log _e\left( \frac{r}{{{r}_{0}}} \right)$, where $r_0$ is a constant. Assuming Bohr’s model to be applicable, find variation of $r_n$ with $n$, where $n$ being the principal quantum number.
**My attempt:** Can't even figure out where to start form. Any guidance please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write down the electric potential energy

$$U = eV = e V_{0}ln(\frac{r}{r_0})$$

we know $\vec{F}=-\nabla U$ but in this case

$$\vec{F}=-\frac{d}{dr}e V_{0}ln(\frac{r}{r_0}) = -eV_{0}\frac{1}{r}$$

centripetal force should be equal to $|\vec{F}|$ as follows

$$\frac{mv^2}{r} = \frac{e V_{0}}{r}$$

thus $v = \sqrt{\frac{eV_{0}}{m}}$. As stated in the question, assume Bohr model so electron moves in circular orbits where $2\pi r = n\lambda$ , de-Broglie wavelength is defined as

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{mv}$$

After substitution, you'll get

$$2\pi r = n\frac{h}{mv} \Rightarrow r_{n}=n\frac{h}{2\pi mv}$$

use the $\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi}$ and $v = \sqrt{\frac{eV_{0}}{m}}$ relations to simplify $r_{n}$ finally it becomes

$$r_{n} = \frac{n\hbar}{\sqrt{meV_{0}}}$$